# Solve non linear equation at different value of parameter

Tags: matlab

I need to solve a non linear equation involving one variable in variable.
e.g. `f(x)=x^1.9+(1-x)*(1-2*x)-1.2545=0`

However, there is small complication. The equation also involves one parameter say `t` and I need to solve the equation for various values of t which I have defined in a vector.

```
t=0.1:0.1:5.0;
f(x)=t*x^1.9+...+52.25*t=0
solution=[solutions for each value of t]
```

How do I go about this?
I have considered concating a string and then building an inline function out of it and then using fsolve. But I think that's not the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters into the objective function using anonymous functions.
First define an objective function that takes **two** arguments `x` *and* `t`

```
 myFun = @( x, t ) t.*x.^1.9 + ( 1 - x ).*( 1 - 2 * x ) + 52.25*t;
```

Now you can change `t` each time:

```
 ts = 0.1:0.1:5;
 for ti = 1:numel(ts)
     t = ts(ti); % current value for t
     solution(ti) = fsolve( @(x) myFun( x, t ), x0 );
 end
```